# How to enable location and enable toolbar inside of a fragment_map.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I have been able to display Google Maps to display inside the fragment, but I cannot do anything else with it! I just have the main activity pointing to the MapFragment.java file which points to the map_fragment.xml file.

fragment_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
map:cameraBearing="0"
map:cameraTargetLat="29.7189"
map:cameraTargetLng="-95.3392"
map:cameraTilt="0"
map:cameraZoom="13"
map:mapType="normal"
map:uiCompass="true"
map:uiRotateGestures="true"
map:uiScrollGestures="true"
map:uiTiltGestures="true"
map:uiZoomControls="true"
map:uiZoomGestures="true"/>
```

this is the MapFragment.java file

```
package info.teammumu.cougarcardapp;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

public MapFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What do you meant by Toolbar? Do you mean the search bar? If you want to enable location, you can do `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

Comment: like to make a search inside the application. I assume the googleMap.setMy... needs to be put into the .java file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable location, you can add a GoogleMap instance variable:

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;
```

Then you need to setMyLocationEnabled() to true:

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

If you need a search toolbar, you need to add an `EditText` view or a `AutoCompleteTextView` in your XML layout, you can read [this tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/) for more details, and [this Google Maps official page.](https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android)